# Can't use checked/unchecked checkbox logic on table rows

Tags: javascript, angularjs, camunda, camunda-modeler

I want to add check  all checkbox  to  my table  which  will be able to collect  checked data  into  one  array ( i am  making  this  into camunda  embedded forms  environment)
here is  my  code  which should  help me  make  this:

```
$scope.checkAll = function () {
        if ($scope.selectedAll) {
            $scope.selectedAll = true;
        } else {
            $scope.selectedAll = false;
        }
        angular.forEach($scope.selectedDocuments, function (item) {
            item.selectedDocuments = $scope.selectedAll;
        });

    };
```

p.s selectedDocuments  is  my  array

here is  my   html code:

```
<table name ="table" id="myTable" class="table table-hover  table-list-search" data-table="order-table" style="width:100%;" cellspacing="0">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th style="width:80px; height:25px;"><input style="width:25px; height:25px;" type="checkbox" ng-model="selectedAll" ng-click="checkAll()"></th>
                    <th style="width:140px;">id</th>
                    <th style="width:305px;">organizationName</th>
                    <th style="width:305px;">priority</th>
                     <th>&nbsp;</th>
                </tr>           
            </thead>
            <tbody ng-repeat="item in jsonData" >
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" ng-change="sync(item.Selected, item)"  ng-checked="isChecked(item.id) ng-model="item.Selected""  /></td> 
                    <td>{{item.id}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.organizationName}}</td>

                     <td>{{item.priority}}</td>                   
                     <td><button class="btn btn-default btn-xs" ng-click="toggle($index)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span></button></td>


    </tr>   
    </table>
```

but  when  i  deploy  this  code  i  usually  got  this  error:
unexpected  tokens or if  it  deployes  without  error i  can't  select  all td-es  on  main  checkbox  click( i  mean  if  it  deployees  without  errors  i  can't use  it  properly)
what  should  i change  to  make  this  code  work?

Answer (score 0):

Unexpected token is a syntax error in your HTML.

This:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" ng-change="sync(item.Selected, item)"  ng-checked="isChecked(item.id) ng-model="item.Selected""  /></td>
```

should be:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" ng-change="sync(item.Selected, item)"  ng-checked="isChecked(item.id)" ng-model="item.Selected" /></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides the syntax error, this condition is wrong and won't do nothing:

```
if ($scope.selectedAll) {
    $scope.selectedAll = true;
} else {
    $scope.selectedAll = false;
}
```

It should be the opposite:

```
    if (!$scope.selectedAll) {
        $scope.selectedAll = true;
    } else {
        $scope.selectedAll = false;
    }
```

If selectedAll is false then set it to true.